# How to create a custom Class - Selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium

using pycharm, python 3.10, selenium 4.5 chrome Version 106.0.5249.119 and chromedriver 106.0.5249.61.
If someone could assist me in structuring my class with multiple files please I would be very appreciative! I think I am not passing through the attributes in the class correctly or importing the packages correctly into it.

Im working from this simple/flat code which works perfect:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
   
s = Service("C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk")
```

Now I am trying to create a Class in its own file:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class Scrape(webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe'))):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Scrape, self).__init__()
```

the run.py file is

```
from folder.scrape import Scrape

inst = Scrape()
inst.get("http://www.google.co.uk")
inst.maximisewindow ....etc
el1 = inst.findelement.......etc
```

the error message im getting
File "C:\folder\scrape.py", line 12, in 
class Scrape(webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('C:\SeleniumDrivers\chromedriver.exe'))):
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in **init**
super().**init**(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 82, in **init**
if options._ignore_local_proxy:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this action `webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe'))` creates an object 
so by this line `class Scrape(webdriver.Chrome(service=Service('C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')))` you actually inherit `Scrape` class not from `webdriver.Chrome` but from newly created object of that class
you'd better do it like this:

```
class Scrape(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Scrape, self).__init__(service=Service('C:\\SeleniumDrivers\\chromedriver.exe'))
```

here we call the constructor of `webdriver.Chrome` passing into it needed `service` argument

Comment: thats it! thank you so much. that was driving me crazy